# (LIBGDX) Rendering Sprite (character) hides a Wall

Tags: java, dictionary, libgdx, render, tiled

I'm making a game with Libgdx and I'm using isometric perspective.
I have a problem when rendering my character because the map is loaded from Tiled Map Editor and character is a Sprite.

If I have a wall on layer 0 of the map, when drawing the wall before the Sprite, if the sprite is behind the wall, we will see the Sprite instead of wall (we should see the wall), if rendering the Sprite first, we will see the wall instead of the Sprite when the sprite is in front of the wall (we should see the Sprite). Any idea about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't really worked with tiled maps, but I think it goes something like this.

First, in TileEd, create an object layer that will be used for your character sprite. So the layer should be between background stuff and stuff that should obscure your player. Name it something like "characters".

Then, create a MapObject subclass that can render a sprite. Something like this:

```
public class SpriteMapObject extends MapObject {

    private Sprite sprite;

    public SpriteMapObject (Sprite sprite) {
        this.sprite = sprite;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor () {
        return sprite.getColor();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColor(Color color){
        sprite.setColor(color);
    }

    public void render(Batch batch){
        Color spriteColor = sprite.getColor();
        float originalAlpha = spriteColor.a;
        spriteColor.a *= getOpacity();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        spriteColor.a = originalAlpha;
    }
}
```

Now after you load your map and your sprite, you can put the sprite on that layer you prepared:

```
map.getLayers().get("characters").add(new SpriteMapObject(playerSprite));
```

You also need to subclass the map renderer so it will render the sprite for you. Use your subclassed version instead of the original. For instance:

```
public class SpritesOrthogonalTiledMapRenderer extends OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer {

    //Override whichever constructor(s) you need
    public SpritesOrthogonalTiledMapRenderer (TiledMap map, Batch batch) {
        super(map, batch);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderObject(MapObject object) {
        super.renderObject(object);
        if(object instanceof SpriteMapObject) {
            ((SpriteMapObject) object).render(batch);
        }
    }
}
```

That's the basics of how it works. But if you want your player to be able to be in front or behind of a wall like you described, then you will need to create multiple extra layers, and move your sprite object to different layers when necessary.

Looks to me like Libgdx could use a feature enhancement to OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer so it can draw objects automatically merged into a TileLayer and inserting them into the draw order based on row.

Comment: Still the same problem, I don't know how to check when the sprite should be rendered first or last..

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a trivial way to do it in libgdx. I think you would need to make several layers in TileEd, one layer for each row of objects that can be either behind or in front of the player, with the layers sorted such that closer rows are higher layers. Then create object rows in between all of those and move your player from layer to layer as their own row changes. All this would be much easier if libgdx could automatically test the Y of the player against the Y of the problematic tiles and draw the player mixed into the layer correctly.

Comment: the thing is it might work but I'm not planning on use only 1 player, my game will be like Age of Empires where a lot of players should check wether they're in front of or behind a problematic tile, I think it will cost too much

Comment: Even if support for this were built into libgdx, you would still have the cost of checking each player's depth and sorting them into the layers. But I don't think the cost of something simple like that is worth worrying about, unless you have thousands of on-screen characters at once. Automating this feels like something that could easily be added to libgdx, but I haven't messed around with TileEd before. Maybe some day if I'm bored I'll take a stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

I found an "answer" somewhere else so I share it with you so if any1 else had the problem:

```
- get players tile location.
- get each tile in that stack ( aka, get a reference to every tile in that cell across each layer.
- check for visibility exceptions on each of those tiles. Store exceptions as properties defined in Tiled. ( will cover properties shortly )
- handle accordingly, most likely by raising or lowering the players render layer for that frame.
```